# Is there a free BAR GRAPH (2d) class for flash cs3/cs4 (AS 3.0)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is there a free/open source  BAR GRAPH (2d) component or sample file for Flash cs3/cs4

I found a few options for Actionscript2, but I need to use actionscript 3.0

(its preferred to load data from external source, loadvars or similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/

Comment: It doesn't require the Flex framework, but it is a complex set of classes by itself.  If your graph requirements are static, you might get by with scaling the height of design-time placed rectangular sprites. For example, rect1.height = value * scaleFactor; would be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can give [Yahoo's Flash CS3 Charts](http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/astra-flash/charts/) a go as well...they're really easy to use.